# From the graph of a quadratic equation, find the range of values of $x$.

Tags: quadratics

[image]

The equation of the graph is
$$
y = -x^2 + 9x - 18
$$

From the graph sketched, find the range of values of $x$ for which $x^2 + 18 > 9x$.

Workings
$$
y = -(x-3)(x-6)
$$

I'm not sure what is the question asking ...
Can I get a hint? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is asking for what values of $x$ the expression $-x^2+9x-18$ is negative. The answer is obvious from the graph or from your factorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

note that:

$9x<x^2-18 \iff -x^2+9x-18<0$

and look at your graph.